# RecyclerView only lists first item despite layout changes

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I understand this might be a duplicate, but every other solution here didn't work in my case, such as changing the `layout_height` to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

My `Firestore` database has 2 values stored inside an array, and I want to display both of them (more in the future) in my RecyclerView, however, it only displays the first value, at position 0.

Here is my `Activity` where the `Recycler` and the `Adapter` are created:

### ActivityOs

```
 private FirestoreAdapter listAdapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference osRef = db.collection("cliente");
    private DocumentReference docRef = osRef.document("clienteTeste");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_os);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOs);

        /*docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.e("RESULTADO","result:" + document.toString());
                }
            }
        });*/

        Query query = osRef.orderBy("serviceOrder",
                Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceDocument> options =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ServiceDocument>()
                        .setQuery(osRef, ServiceDocument.class)
                        .build();

         listAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        listAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        listAdapter.stopListening();
    }
```

The commented code shows me that the database does indeed return the 2 values stored in it.

### Here is my `Adapter` class:

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ServiceDocument, FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceDocument> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ServiceDocument model) {
        holder.osIdItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.serviceOrderArray.get(position).getId()));
        holder.osClientItem.setText(model.serviceOrderArray.get(position).getClient().getName());
        holder.osDateItem.setText(model.serviceOrderArray.get(position).getDate());
        holder.osValueItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.serviceOrderArray.get(position).getTotalValue()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_os_item, parent, false);

        return new FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private  TextView osIdItem;
        private  TextView osClientItem;
        private  TextView osDateItem;
        private  TextView osValueItem;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            osIdItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osIDItem);
            osClientItem =   itemView.findViewById(R.id.osClientNameItem);
            osDateItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osDateItem);
            osValueItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osValueItem);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my layouts, activity_os.xml where my RecyclerView is created, and layout_os_item.xml where the layouts for each item of the recycler are made.

### Activity_os.xml

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_os"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:context="com.leonardomaito.autocommobile.activities.OsActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/layout_header_search" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/glRecyclerLimit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="124dp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewOs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="650dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/glRecyclerLimit"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_os_item" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btNewOs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Inserir OS"
            android:onClick="createNewOs"
            android:src="@drawable/custom_plus_icon"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/autocom_blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/glRecyclerLimit"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.988"
            app:rippleColor="@color/autocom_blue" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Layout_os_item.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_os"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_card_view">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_card_view">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/custom_os_icon"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/osIDItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="N 00000"
            android:textColor="@color/autocom_blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/osDateItem"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/osDateItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/autocom_blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.943"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.222" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/osClientNameItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/autocom_blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/osIDItem"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.111" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/osValueItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="R$ 10,000"
            android:textColor="@color/autocom_blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.791"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/osClientNameItem"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/osDateItem"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Any help is welcome!

### Edit

**Current Result:**

[image: Result]

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected]

Basically, Item 0 or the first item is correct, however, the second item in my database should also appear in Item 1.

Comment: It will be great, if you can add the result and expected view.

Comment: Edited in, apologies.

Comment: Have you try changing wrap_content of constraint layout inside activity_os.xml to match_parent?

Comment: Yes, I have. It now takes the entire screen but only shows the first item still. Actually, it places the first item on the top of the screen, and then shows the rest of the layout elements below It.

Comment: Try changing this app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glRecyclerLimit"      - of recyclerview

Comment: It did make the layout better, but didn't fix the issue where it only displays the item at position 0. Let me run a few more tests to see if I can dig up more issues.

Comment: I did override `public int getItemCount()` in my `Adapter` class, and using the debugger, it returns a size of 0. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check the data count before passing to adapter?